# Votes from users under 15 reputation

Tags: support, reputation, votes

I have a question about my Server Fault post: [VXLAN format details](https://serverfault.com/questions/879106/vxlan-format-details)

Are votes from users under 15 reputation visible to the owners of the comments? Are they notified someway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since votes on comments don’t generate any reputation they don’t result in the  notification of a change in reputation to the author.

Votes on answers (and questions) by any user allowed to vote will result in a change in reputation and notification thereof  that links to the question/answer that was voted on.

Only by referring to @alias in a comment will a notification by sent to user `alias`

https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment